# Unable to fetch the data from firebase child using React Redux-Saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I am unable to fetch firebase child data with React and Redux-Saga. Can you please check the below code ? Why it is not working with redux-saga.

```
import { takeLatest, put, call, fork, all, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { getContactsSuccess, getContactsFail } from "./actions";
import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import firebaseDb from "../firebase";

export function* onGetContactsStartSync() {
  try {
    const snapshot = yield firebaseDb.child("contacts").on("value");

    yield put(getContactsSuccess(snapshot.val()));
    console.log("snapshot", snapshot);
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getContactsFail(error));
  }
}

export function* onLoadContacts() {
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_CONTACTS_START, onGetContactsStartSync);
}

const contactSagas = [fork(onLoadContacts)];

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([...contactSagas]);
}
```

When I tried with redux-thunk then I was able to fetch the data from firebase with the below approach

```
export const getContacts = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(getContactsStart());
    firebaseDb.child("contacts").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      try {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
          dispatch(getContactsSuccess(snapshot.val()));
        } else {
          dispatch(getContactsSuccess({}));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(getContactsFail(error));
      }
    });
  };
};
```

So, what is going wrong with redux-saga approach ? I wanted to replicate the same thing with redux-saga.

I think i am missing some small thing here, which is might be very basic. Let me know if have some solution.

I tried the below approach as well.

```
function createContactChannel() {
  const listener = eventChannel((emit) => {
    firebaseDb.child("contacts").on("value", (data) => {
      if (data.val() !== null) {
        emit(data.val());
      }
    });
    return () => firebaseDb.child("contacts").off(listener);
  });

  console.log("listener", listener);
  return listener;
}

export function* onGetContactsStartSync() {
  try {
    const contacts = createContactChannel();

    yield put(getContactsSuccess(contacts));

  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getContactsFail(error));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `firebaseDb.child("contacts").on("value")` returning a promise?

Comment: Yes, it return snapshot when we pass callback function as 2nd argument in "on" method. I have tested with redux-thunk it is working fine, I have also mention in the post. But the same thing I am not able to replicate with redux-saga

Comment: I understand you can use callback as 2nd param. My question was whether if you omit the callback it actually returns a promise instead as I am not sure if firebase api uses promises.

Comment: I guess it won't return a promise if we omit callback as 2nd param. Is there any workaround that we can do in redux-saga ?

Comment: You will probably have to write some api layer to convert the callbacks to promises. Inline implementation would look like this (without errors handling): `yield new Promise(resolve => firebaseDb.child("contacts").on("value", resolve))`